# Creating multiple matrices with nested loop using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import random

x = np.linspace(-3.0,3.0,25)

b = 3; a = -3; n = 24
N = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(4,24)));
G = [] #want to save the 2 4by 24 matrices in G
s = []; g = []


Y = []
random.seed(4)

for j in range(0,2):
    Y.append(np.random.randint(-6.0,6.0,size=(4,1)))
    h = (b-a)/float(n)
    s.append(0.5*h*((1+(np.cos((np.pi*(a-Y[j]))/3.0)))))
    g.append(0.5*h*(1+(np.cos((np.pi*(b-Y[j]))/3.0))))
    for k in range(0,Y[j].shape[0]):
        for l in range(1, x.shape[0]-1):
            N[k,l] = h*(1 + (np.cos((np.pi*(x[l]-Y[j][k]))/3.0)))
            N[k,0] = s[j][k]
N = np.concatenate((N,g[j]),axis=1)

print(N)
```

Please, I need help. When I run this code, it produces just a single 4by25 matrix but it is suppose to be 2 4by25 matrix. I dont know why. My goal is to have the 2 4by25 matrices stored to variable G  so that when i call G[0], it produces the first 4by25 and G[1] produces the second 4by25. Here Y outputs 2 4by1 coulmn vectors.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I am confused. You are not doing anything with the G variable and it is hard to tell what are you trying to store inside the 'G'.

Comment: Yeah, that's true.lol. I got tired of using G.append(), because it doesn't work. the point is if i run the loop, I get my first iteration 4x24matrix for j=0, then for j=1 the values then change the first 4by24 matrix producing just one 4x24matrix instead of 2

Comment: Solved it. I had to initialize N at each iteration. So N has to be inside the nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

How is your code supposed to append 2 matrices to G? You are totally missing that part.
I don't really get what values you're looking for, so I can't tell you if values are added correctly, anyway you should add this line:

```
G.append(N)
```

(I'm just assuming you are appending N because it is the only 2x24 matrix)
Before the end of the first cylce, result should be something like:

```
for j in range(0,2):
    Y.append(np.random.randint(-6.0,6.0,size=(4,1)))
    h = (b-a)/float(n)
    s.append(0.5*h*((1+(np.cos((np.pi*(a-Y[j]))/3.0)))))
    g.append(0.5*h*(1+(np.cos((np.pi*(b-Y[j]))/3.0))))
    for k in range(0,Y[j].shape[0]):
        for l in range(1, x.shape[0]-1):
            N[k,l] = h*(1 + (np.cos((np.pi*(x[l]-Y[j][k]))/3.0)))
            N[k,0] = s[j][k]
    N = np.concatenate((N,g[j]),axis=1)
    G.append(N)
```

Comment: yeah i tried that, and still does not work. The Y results into two separate 4x1 vectors. Y[0] and Y[1] are different. so my goal is to produce a separate 4x24 matrix which is N[k,l] for Y[0] and Y[1]. And then putting them into an empty array. Hope you get me now

Comment: No, I don't get you. The empty array should contain what? What does "them" refer to? Y[0] and Y[1]? 
That's a messy code, it's hard to get what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, let me come again. the empty array should contain two separate matrices.for example the empty array is G, if what i want is achieved then if I call G[0] it should give me a 4x24matrix and G[1] another 4x24matrix.

Comment: So that's what it does!
G will have shape 2,4,24...
If you print(G) you'll see it!
The misunderstanding is maybe due to the fact that you are appending to G (which is a simple tuple) a np.matrix. So what G sees is just an array composed by 2 elements, each of them is a 4 line single element (the array).

To correctly access each element (let's say the first one) you should do something like G[0][0,0] - first index is the element of the 2 matrices, second are the coordinates of the np.matrix

Comment: E.G.

1) First matrix => G[0]

2) First line of the first matrix => G[0][0,:]

3) First column of the first matrix => G[0][:,0]
And so on

Comment: Okay, cool. I will try that. Another thing is within the nested loop, when j=0, you will get the 4x24matrix, but when j=1,it changes every values in the first 4x24matrix when j=0. So the output is just only one 1x4x24 matrix instead of 2x4x24. So, what should i do such that i could get both 4x24matrices separately. You can run the code and see what am talking about.